# Error initializing filter 'amovie' when Join multiple files and add background music, watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

I am doing concatenation of multiple videos with adding background music and watermark at the same time (see below)

```
[-y, -i, 012.mp4, -i, 011.mp4, -i, 010.mp4, -i, 009.mp4, -i, 008.mp4, -i, 007.mp4, -i, 006.mp4, -i, 005.mp4, -i, 004.mp4, -i, 003.mp4, -i, 002.mp4, -i, 001.mp4, -i, 000.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/FXMotion/.cache/.watermark/logo_watermark.png, -filter_complex, [0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a][5:v][5:a][6:v][6:a][7:v][7:a][8:v][8:a][9:v][9:a][10:v][10:a][11:v][11:a][12:v][12:a]concat=n=13:v=1:a=1[video][audio];[13:v]scale=320:-1[watermark];[video][watermark]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[vw];amovie=/storage/emulated/0/Download/Afro B - Drogba (Joanna) Prod by Team Salut [Official Music Video].mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[bgmusic];[audio]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0[fmaudio];[fmaudio][bgmusic]amerge=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout], -map, [vw], -map, [aout], -c:v, libx264, -crf, 18, -preset, veryfast, -shortest, temp.mp4, -hide_banner]
```

When I run the above command, it has an error:

```
[Parsed_amovie_3 @ 0x816c5c00] Failed to avformat_open_input '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Afro B - Drogba (Joanna) Prod by Team Salut'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xa4c104c0] Error initializing filter 'amovie'[AVFilterGraph @ 0xa4c104c0]  with args '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Afro B - Drogba (Joanna) Prod by Team Salut'[AVFilterGraph @ 0xa4c104c0]
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory
Conversion failed!
```

I don't know why it happened, is it a bug of amovie filter?

how to solve it ?, thank advance.

*----------------Full Log------------------*

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '012.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:04.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5349 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5340 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 12800 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '011.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:06.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5642 kb/s
Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5681 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '010.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:06.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5689 kb/s
Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5695 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '009.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:06.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5624 kb/s
Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5630 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #3:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '008.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:05.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5226 kb/s
Stream #4:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5218 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 12800 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #4:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '007.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:06.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5631 kb/s
Stream #5:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5663 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #5:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '006.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:06.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5455 kb/s
Stream #6:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5472 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #6:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '005.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:06.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5220 kb/s
Stream #7:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5213 kb/s, 19.81 fps, 19.81 tbr, 720k tbn, 39.61 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #7:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #8, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '004.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:05.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5515 kb/s
Stream #8:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5542 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 12800 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #8:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #9, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '003.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:06.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4450 kb/s
Stream #9:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 4445 kb/s, 15.25 fps, 15.25 tbr, 15616 tbn, 30.50 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #9:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #10, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '002.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:05.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4323 kb/s
Stream #10:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 4321 kb/s, 20.29 fps, 20.29 tbr, 1800k tbn, 40.58 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #10:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #11, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '001.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:05.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3759 kb/s
Stream #11:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 3776 kb/s, 16.19 fps, 16.19 tbr, 1350k tbn, 32.38 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #11:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #12, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '000.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
location-eng    : +18.0104-077.0263/
location        : +18.0104-077.0263/
Duration: 00:00:07.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5448 kb/s
Stream #12:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 5441 kb/s, 16.53 fps, 16.53 tbr, 10800k tbn, 33.06 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #12:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #13, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/FXMotion/.cache/.watermark/logo_watermark.png':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #13:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 335x51, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[Parsed_amovie_3 @ 0x816c5c00] Failed to avformat_open_input '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Afro B - Drogba (Joanna) Prod by Team Salut'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xa4c104c0] Error initializing filter 'amovie'[AVFilterGraph @ 0xa4c104c0]  with args '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Afro B - Drogba (Joanna) Prod by Team Salut'[AVFilterGraph @ 0xa4c104c0]
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `[` and `]` in the MP3 file name:

```
[-y, -i, 012.mp4, -i, 011.mp4, -i, 010.mp4, -i, 009.mp4, -i, 008.mp4, -i, 007.mp4, -i, 006.mp4, -i, 005.mp4, -i, 004.mp4, -i, 003.mp4, -i, 002.mp4, -i, 001.mp4, -i, 000.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/FXMotion/.cache/.watermark/logo_watermark.png, -filter_complex, [0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a][5:v][5:a][6:v][6:a][7:v][7:a][8:v][8:a][9:v][9:a][10:v][10:a][11:v][11:a][12:v][12:a]concat=n=13:v=1:a=1[video][audio];[13:v]scale=320:-1[watermark];[video][watermark]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[vw];amovie=/storage/emulated/0/Download/Afro B - Drogba (Joanna) Prod by Team Salut \[Official Music Video\].mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[bgmusic];[audio]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0[fmaudio];[fmaudio][bgmusic]amerge=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout], -map, [vw], -map, [aout], -c:v, libx264, -crf, 18, -preset, veryfast, -shortest, temp.mp4, -hide_banner]
```

Or rename the file so it does not contain `[]`.